# use regex to extract digits before last matched occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string logs as follow:

`rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 0px 16px inset`

I like to get the dynamic value, in the case above, 16. How do I write regex for the rule to match the last `px` then take out the digits between `px` and the space?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: /\d\d(?=px)/  it does the work but not quite the rules above

Comment: change `\d\d` to `\d+` in your regex

Comment: that would match 0 0 0 16

Comment: will the string have  `inset` at the end always?

Comment: yeah, its a css property `box-shadow`

Comment: in that case try `\d+(?=px inset)`

Comment: @Matt.G I'd say you should post that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you just want the number before the *last* `px`, I won't assume that the text `inset` is always there. I would say `\b\d+(?=px\b(?!.*\b\d+px\b))` is probably your safest bet.

Comment: In case someone is interested I'll explain how this one works: `\b\d+` matches the begining of words that are digits, `(?=` is like an "and" operator as it checks if the following condition is also met, `px` checks if px is after the digit `(?!` is like a "not" operator as it checks if the following condition does not occur, and finally `\b\d+px\b` checks the same pattern as the beginning. In short it checks that the pattern "digit+px" exists and that after it, the same pattern does not occur again, so matches the last occurence.

Comment: In case you want to test it, here it is in regex101. BTW, a very good site for creating and test your regexp's https://regex101.com/r/V11BVd/1

Comment: yeah I was using Regex101 to test. Thanks for all the detailed posted above!